# Is this a valid definition of the partial derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

**Context**: Suppose we have defined what the derivative of functions of the form $\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^n$ are. I am trying to define the partial derivative of a function $\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ formally and in a way that seems intuitive to me, however I am not sure if it is quite correct/the usual way.

Let $f:\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ be a function. Then for all $a \in \mathbf{R}$ we have a function $f_a: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^2, b \mapsto f(a,b).$ This is a function of one variable which we know how to differentiate. Hence we have a function  $g: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R^2}, b \mapsto f_a'(a,b),$ where $f_a'$ is the derivative of $f_a$.

This now gives us a function $\partial_yf:\mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{R}^2$ in the following way. Suppose $c \in \mathbf{R}^2$. Then there are $a,b \in \mathbf{R}$ satsisfying $c=(a,b)$. Now, since we have a function $f_a$ for any real valued $a$, we know that there exists a unique $f'_a(b) \in \mathbf{R}^2.$ We then define $\partial_y f(c):=f_a'(b)$ and obtain a function as desired. This function is then called the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$.

I think that this is somewhat the same definition as shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative, but I am not entirely sure. Furthermore it should be possible to generalize this to $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Comment: yes that's right, though you have a notational mistake. $f_a$ has domain $\Bbb{R}$, hence $f_a'$ also has domain $\Bbb{R}$. So, you should be writing $b\mapsto f_a'(b)$, not $b\mapsto f_a'(a,b)$. So, $f_a'(b)=(\partial_yf)(a,b)$, or another common notation is $(\partial_2f)(a,b)$, since we're differentiating with respect to the second variable.

Comment: This definition is essentially no different from the typical one involving limits, only more cumbersome.